# Can matlab find multiple peaks in a plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

obviously i'm newbie in matlab programming. My teacher gave us a problem about programming, he want us to make a program using matlab that can find/locate peak/s from a data plot, it's a kind of peak finder. i can do this using origin pro and scilab (which are peak finder software) so can matlab do that? thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to understand how to do it. What mathematical tricks can you use to find a peak? How is a peak point defined in any function? Think about derivatives.

Comment: i try this command:

x=[0:.01:50];y=cos(x);
P=findpeaksG(x,y,0,-1,5,5)

but i got an error: Undefined function 'findpeaksG' for input arguments of
type 'double'.

Error in peakfinder (line 2)
P=findpeaksG(x,y,0,-1,5,5)

Comment: "he want us to **make a program** using matlab that can find/locate peak/s" probably doesn't mean: "write a program that uses findpeaks()".

Comment: yes you have a point, maybe our teacher don't want us to used findpeaks(), so what other option or syntax may i use? thanks.

Comment: @matlabnewbie - I've linked you to a post where you can do what `findpeaks` is doing by first principles.  Take a look at that post as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `findpeaks` function:

```
x = [0:.01:50];
y = cos(x);
[val, pos] = findpeaks(y, x)
  val =
     1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
  pos =
     6.2800   12.5700   18.8500   25.1300   31.4200   37.7000   43.9800
```

Or, if you want something more graphical:

```
x = [0:.01:50];
y = cos(x);
plot(x, y);
findpeaks(y, x);
```

In any case, you should check `findpeaks` documentation for more info:

```
doc findpeaks
```